# How Select The Rows In A Dataframe with the Maximum Value in a Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to select all the rows that

```
df =  A  B C D
     'a' 1 1 1
     'b' 1 2 1
     'c' 1 1 1
     'a' 1 2 2
     'a' 2 2 2
     'b' 1 2 2
```

And I want to get the rows where the value in one column is the maximum for that group. So for the example above if I wanted to group be 'A' and 'B' and get the rows that have the greatest value in 'C'

```
df = A  B C D
    'a' 1 2 2
    'b' 1 2 2
    'c' 1 1 1
    'a' 2 2 2
```

I know that I want to use a `groupby`, but I'm not sure what to do after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the transform function. This basically let's you apply a function against a group that retains the same index as the original dataframe. In this case, you can see you get the following from the transform

```
In [13]: df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform(max)
Out[13]: 
0    2
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

This has the exact same index as the original dataframe, so you can use it to create a filter.

```
df[df['C'] == df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform(max)]
Out[11]: 
   A  B  C  D
1  b  1  2  1
2  c  1  1  1
3  a  1  2  2
4  a  2  2  2
5  b  1  2  2
```

For much more information on this, see [the pandas groupby documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html), which is excellent.